# I can't disable scroll bars in Mavericks any more

Tags: scrollbar, osx-mavericks

I was trying to find a work-around to the software for Griffin PowerMate not working in Mavericks by using the switch control options, while I was tweaking settings the scroll bar option was changed to always show. But, even now I've turned switch control off again, I cannot get scrollbars to stop showing. If I change the setting to automatic or when scrolling, nothing changes, and when I relaunch system prefs it goes back to always.

Even if I run `sudo defaults write -g AppleShowScrollBars WhenScrolling` there are no errors, but it has no effect.

Any ideas how I can get them to go away again?

Comment: I've the same problem... simply can't set this anymore.